# Cant get the scroll wheel to see items out of bounds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to create a ReactJS portfolio. I have props that are in my ProjectData.js file, and I can see them on my screen.
However, I only see 3 items, the rest are beyond the window size and I can't scroll to see them. I was wondering if I can get some help to see the other cards that are created.

I am trying to use framer-motion for the scroll wheel animation, but I don't think it's registering the scroll wheel listener.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import AnimatedLetters from '../AnimatedLetters'
import Loader from 'react-loaders'
import './index.scss'

import { Projects } from '../data/ProjectData'

import Card from '../subComponents/Card'
import { LoadIcon } from './AllSvgs'

import { motion, useScroll } from 'framer-motion'
import styled from 'styled-components'


const Box = styled.div`

`

const Main = styled(motion.ul)`


`

const Rotate = styled.span`

`

const transitionEffect = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0 },
  show: {
    opacity: 1,

    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.5,
      duration: 0.5
    }
  }

}

const Proj = () => {
  const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate')

  const ref = useRef(null)
  const initialIcon = useRef(null)


  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current

    const rotate = () => {
      element.style.transform = `translateX(${-window.pageYOffset}px)`

      return (initialIcon.current.style.transform =
        'rotate(' + -window.pageYOffset + 'deg)')
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', rotate)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', rotate)
    }
  }, [])

  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({ container: ref });

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 3000)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container proj-page">
        <div className="text-zone">
          <h1>
            <AnimatedLetters
              letterClass={letterClass}
              strArray={[
                'P',
                'r',
                'e',
                'v',
                'i',
                'o',
                'u',
                's',
                ' ',
                'E',
                'x',
                'p',
                'e',
                'r',
                'i',
                'e',
                'n',
                'c',
                'e',
                's'
              ]}
              idx={10}
            />
          </h1>

          {/* TODO: CARDS WITH PREV PROJECTS */}
          <div className='Projects-display'>
            <Box >
              <Main ref={ref}
                variants={transitionEffect}
                initial='hidden'
                animate='show' > {
                  Projects.map(wd =>

                    <Card key={wd.id}
                      data={wd}
                    />
                  )
                } </Main>

              <Rotate ref={initialIcon} >
                <LoadIcon width={80}
                  height={80}
                  fill="#000000"
                /> </Rotate>
            </Box>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Proj
```